# seaborn scatterplotにおいて、凡例(hue)に数値のものをいれるとプロット色が濃淡になってしまう

Tags: python, pandas

seaborn のversion0.10.0を使用しております。

seaborn scatterplotにおいて、凡例(hue)に数値のものをいれるとプロット色が濃淡になってしまいます。
やりたいこととしては出力図の凡例をカラフルな色にしたいと考えております。
通常はカラフルになるのですが、凡例対象が数値であるため濃淡なものになってしまいます。

図にしたいデータ
[image: dataframe]
現在の出力図

```
sns.scatterplot(x="latitude", y="longitude",data=cluster_df,hue='place_cluster')
```

[image: 現在の出力図]

このような凡例のようにカラフルに変更したいです。
[image: 出力イメージ凡例]

Comment: ソースコードや使うデータはスクリーンショットではなくテキストで実行できる過不足ない内容で記述してください。データは大きすぎるなら再現できる程度に少なくするか、入手方法を記述してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hue に数値型のデータを指定したことにより、paletteとしてシーケンシャルデータ用のカラーパレットが設定されたのかと思われますので、元通りのカラフルな色でプロットしたいのであれば、カテゴリー用のカラーパレットを明示的に指定するだけで良いのではないでしょうか。

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

```
sns.scatterplot(x="latitude", y="longitude",data=cluster_df,hue='place_cluster', palette='bright')
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。無事表示したい図を作成することができました。

Answer (score 1):

この記事を参考に、こんな感じで出来ました。
[How To Specify Colors to Scatter Plots in Python?](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/04/how-to-specify-colors-to-scatter-plots-in-python/)

各値用の色指定を辞書で作って、`palette`パラメータに指定することで出来ます。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
cdf = pd.read_csv('st0422_8.csv',header=0)

color_dict = dict({0:'blue',
                   1:'orange',
                   2:'green',
                   3:'red',
                   4:'purple',
                   5:'brown',
                   6:'pink',
                   7:'olive'
                  })

sns.scatterplot(x="longitude", y="latitude", data=cdf, palette=color_dict, hue='place_cluster')
plt.show()
```

こちらがデータです。

```
city,place_cluster,latitude,longitude
所沢市,7,35.799672,139.46861
さいたま市,7,35.861651,139.645435
川口市,6,35.807738,139.724171
越谷市,6,35.891084,139.790938
川越市,5,35.925101,139.485793
入間市,5,35.835766,139.391058
草加市,5,35.825355,139.805402
春日部市,5,35.975198,139.752301
狭山市,5,35.852942,139.412213
戸田市,5,35.817616,139.677892
和光市,4,35.781208,139.605793
志木市,4,35.83675,139.580319
新座市,4,35.793511,139.565369
熊谷市,4,36.14731,139.388645
八潮市,4,35.822536,139.839175
ふじみ野市,4,35.879538,139.519764
朝霞市,3,35.797252,139.593916
富士見市,3,35.856759,139.549074
三郷市,3,35.830149,139.872275
鶴ヶ島市,3,35.934515,139.393098
深谷市,3,36.197444,139.281464
飯能市,3,35.855731,139.327734
上尾市,3,35.977381,139.593206
加須市,2,36.131438,139.601719
蓮田市,2,35.994307,139.662106
白岡市,2,36.019026,139.676925
三芳町,2,35.828367,139.526432
久喜市,2,36.061995,139.666838
伊奈町,2,36.000112,139.624185
毛呂山町,2,35.941501,139.316067
ときがわ町,2,36.00862,139.296844
秩父市,1,35.992055,139.084817
本庄市,1,36.243568,139.190393
羽生市,1,36.172626,139.548465
桶川市,1,36.005779,139.542531
幸手市,1,36.078072,139.725861
日高市,1,35.907796,139.339026
川島町,1,35.982014,139.481518
吉見町,1,36.039853,139.453728
宮代町,1,36.022682,139.722885
杉戸町,1,36.025765,139.736709
蕨市,1,35.825634,139.679708
美里町,1,36.177104,139.18141
神川町,1,36.213876,139.101776
上里町,1,36.251607,139.144826
行田市,0,36.138949,139.455643
東松山市,0,36.042126,139.399959
鴻巣市,0,36.065758,139.522169
北本市,0,36.026768,139.530211
坂戸市,0,35.95717,139.402905
吉川市,0,35.891152,139.841375
越生町,0,35.964478,139.294199
滑川町,0,36.065987,139.360917
嵐山町,0,36.056655,139.320542
小川町,0,36.056697,139.261845
鳩山町,0,35.981466,139.334101
横瀬町,0,35.987284,139.100046
皆野町,0,36.07084,139.098754
長瀞町,0,36.114803,139.109717
小鹿野町,0,36.017129,139.008574
東秩父村,0,36.058153,139.194607
寄居町,0,36.118348,139.193012
松伏町,0,35.925774,139.815178
```

そしてこれが表示結果です。
[image: seaborn_hue色指定]

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。各色辞書指定で表示できたのですね。参考記事もありがとうございます。